# White background for colorbar tick label

Tags: matlab, background, colorbar

Who do I apply a white background for the `colorbar` tick labels? (I use a jet colormap in which black text is hardly visual - changing the text color to white doesn't help either)

A typical workaround for text such as:

```
h = text(0.1,0.1,'some text','units','normalized','color','k','background','w');
```

isn't working; seems that `background` doesn't apply for `colorbar`.

Comment: Can you post the full code? I am not sue what do you meant to white backgroud in the colorbar labels. Will setting the whole background of the image work?

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I could think of is to set the figure background to white, so everything is seen better.

```
figure('Color',[1 1 1]);
[c, h] = contour(peaks/30);
clabel(c, h)
cb = colorbar
```

[image]

Comment: I find a light gray background often improves readability depending on the colors.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan very likely. This is from 2014, there was a completely different rendering engine back then!